# What does `declare module '*! <rest>' stands for?`

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I saw many times a module declaration that uses the `*!` in the module declaration string, what does it stand for?

**Example:** `declare module '*!path/to/module' {}`

I cannot seem to find any explanation for it in the typescript docs.
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

! says the operand before the !, is non-null and non-undefined in where the typescript  is unable to infer it on it's own so the tyscript can assume the operand before the symbol is a valid one. it comes handy whenever we set some properties to optional and later using it. so when we say somewhere in the code,

```
interface f<T extends { x: string }> { 
 id: number,
 data?: T
}
```

and somewhere later we reference like `data!.x`, typescript should assume that the data object is not null or undefined.